# A non-US citizen getting a US credit card

Tags: united-states, credit-card, non-resident

I'm a non-US citizen who would like to get a credit card from the US for iTunes Store US purchases.

Up until now I've been purchasing iTunes Gift Cards from Apple Store US but now it seems that they also require a US credit card.

Is there any way of getting any kind of a US credit card outside the US without a US citizenship or address? I've also heard that UPS provides PMBs(private mail box). Is it also possible for non-US citizens? If so, could this help me for a US credit card?

Or is there any other way?

Comment: Re: *"seems that they also require a US credit card"*. Are you sure? This hasn't been my own experience. I use only the gift cards myself for U.S. iTunes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [US Credit/Debit Card for non-US citizen](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/23221/us-credit-debit-card-for-non-us-citizen)

Comment: @littleadv I saw that question before but I wanted to start a new one since this matter keeps changing.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea Unfortunately that seems to be the case from now on. :(

Comment: @Can that would be another reason to close a question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need "credit card" to buy things from internet, you can use US debit-cards (they are usually MasterCard or Visa, therefore accepted for internet transactions), or something like "prepaid credit card", which is common here in Germany. This is when you get a MasterCard or Visa which is directly linked to your checking account, and your bank account is immediately charged on purchase.

Comment: could please share a little more on this like how can I achieve getting a debit card from the states when I'm not in the states.

Comment: You would "simply" need to open a US bank account. I think there is another question here answering that.

Answer (score 3):

It's going to be pretty hard because you have no credit rating and are realistically beyond our legal system.  If you didn't pay what could they do about it?